# How to create mask clone with concurrent mode support?

Tags: java

I am creating application for capturing signatures from signature device. I am using java - NetBeans project.

I would like to create form clone so it could work in concurrent mode. Idea is to open two form, one is clone of another. Each form would be on their own screen. First would be on primary monitor, second would be on signature device. When customer would typing in some field, change would be immediately seen in primary monitor and vice versa.

[image: Image:]

Same functionality is presented here:
https://vimeo.com/77511626 (17s)

Any idea how would I achieve this?

Regards, Igor

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical usecase handled by properly used MVC pattern.

In most MVC pattern examples, you have only one view at time, but you can always add more of them.

This concrete funcionality is based on Observer Pattern - you register your two views to one model. When model change, it notifies both of registered views that something change and they should reload with new data.

Comment: This is true. But what about PDF viewer and scroll function? I don't think this could be solved by MVC pattern.

Comment: You did not say anything aobut PDF viewer and scroll function, so I really dont know what you are talking about :)

Comment: Please watch video in first post. You will get better picture what I would like to achieve :)